# increase internet speed using two network card and two ip in the same network

Tags: networking, xubuntu, netplan

I'm installing a server at my university. However the speed of connection is quite slow: Max 10 Mb per second. The server that I'm installing has two network card.
I was wondering if there is a way that I can use two ip addresses (one on each card) to increase speed using the same gateway. However, I need to use at least one ip to ssh to the computer. I hope the info are sufficient to have an idea of my problem.

thanks
Luigi

Comment: See if https://netplan.io/examples and https://netplan.io/reference help you at all.

Comment: Do you mean 10Mbit/s or 10MBytes/s? NICs today normally have 1Gbit/s which gives you 100MB/s. The bottleneck seems to be somewhere else. Look at the supported and actual link speed with `ethtool` and test the speed between two endpoints with `iperf`.

Comment: the output of ethtool is the follow:

Comment: the problem is in the network speed. looking at the example in netplan, i can not find something simular to what i need to do